# Is it possible to change the selected database with the Mysql2 gem?

Tags: mysql, ruby, mysql2

I'd like to change which database the Mysql2::Client is using (e.g. the same as typing "use X" in the mysql command-line) without having to establish a new connection to the DB server.

Is this possible? How?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `select_db`

```
db = Mysql2::Client.new
db.select_db('test')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `query` method to switch databases:

```
db = Mysql2::Client.new
db.query('use test')
# You're now talking to the test database
db.query('use something_else')
# You're now talking to the something_else database
```